# Should i learn C++ or ASM?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm confused should i learn C++ or ASM?
I'm just a hobbyist so no big deal but i need some advise.
thank you

Comment: depends, what are you looking to do?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? C++ and ASM are COMPLETELY different languages.

Comment: If you don't know what to pick, play "heads or tails".

Answer (score 5):

Very Subjective but I would say learn C.  Its the most basic language you will ever need to know.  (If you know it you can grasp how assembly works without learning it).  Then build on it and learn C++.  If you don't know C (pointers, memory management, simple stack/function usage), I would learn it first before piling on C++ (with classes, inheritance, overloads, more complicated memory management).

Thats just my opinion though...

Answer (score 2):

If you're a hobbyist, anything that seems interesting and fun to you will work.

The real question is : what software do you want to make? The project is the important thing.

Then the constraints relative to this kind of software will drive you to make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

C++, ASM is very interesting, but nothing you should nowadays use as your primary language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a hardware hobbyist?  ASM

Are you a game or other software-specific hobbyist?  C++

Are you a My Little Pony hobbyist?  [PonyProg](http://www.lancos.com/prog.html)